# Update database if last update is older than 30min

Tags: php, laravel-4

Maybe is newbie question but since I'm new I can't really find a answer to this. I tried lots of different ways which I found here but still..

What I have is one API which return converted rates `USD/EUR` that's okay and work great.

What I want to make now is to update database with current rate and not updating for next 30min since make lot's of call to the api and page become heavier. I've trying to do it in my `BaseController.php` like this:

```
$thirtyminutes = strtotime("-30 minutes");
$newPrice=Price::all();
foreach ($newPrice as $newP ) {
   if ( strtotime($newP['update_time']) > $thirtyminutes ) {
        echo 'bla';
   } else { echo 'bla bla'; }
}
```

I've got correct answer `bla`.

Real question is how logical to make this since `BaseController` is included everywhere this mean on each page load this will make query to DB to check when rate is last updated and update/or not depending of time. Is it good to have it in BaseController and if not where should I put this?

I'm using Laravel 4.2

Update:
Any idea why this doesn't update table? No errors at all

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = ""; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}   
$query = "select * from Price";

$thirtyminutes = strtotime("-30 minutes");
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        echo $row['price'].'<br/>'; // from db
        echo $thirtyminutes.'<br/>'; // 30min
        echo strtotime($row['update_time']).'<br/>'; // last inserted time
            if ( strtotime($row['update_time']) > $thirtyminutes ) {
                $sql = "UPDATE Price SET price='12312', update_time = NOW()";

            }
        }
}
```

echoes shows on page correct data ( I think ):

```
123.00000000 // which is in database
1476702219 // 30min 
1476694075 // last insert
```

UPDATE: Table

```
 price               update_time
123.00000000         2016-10-17 11:47:55
```

Update: nth

```
$query = "select * from Price";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE Price SET price ='1',update_time =NOW() WHERE update_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)";                  
        }
}
```

Comment: I would take it out completely and have a scheduled job update the prices every XX minutes. Then you don't have to worry about it in your application and you can reduce the update time without any significant load increase.

Comment: scheduled == cronjob you mean?

Comment: You can try to add last updated time to the Cache - https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache.

Comment: Yes, a cronjob that runs separately from your app.

Comment: @xpuc7o thanks. I've already tried to put it in cache but seems like still make calls and load slowly or I didn't make it right.

Comment: Updated my question with simple select/update but doesn't update db even when values are correct.

Comment: Can you show your table please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your update query

```
 $sql = "UPDATE Price SET price ='12312',update_time =NOW() WHERE update_time <=(NOW - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE";
```

Then have a cronjob that will trigger this script every 30 minutes .

Comment: I've updated my question with table. It's just one row.

Comment: You said older than 30 minutes there " if ( strtotime($row['update_time']) > $thirtyminutes ) {"

Change ">" to "<=" $thirtyminutes

Comment: Hm.. still doesn't update. Nothing wrong on the page but doesn't update in db.

Comment: yes, In phpmyadmin is working. That's what I meant by `The IF statement doesn't work`

Comment: You don't need that if statement, the condition is already stated on your query  " WHERE update_time <=(NOW - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE"  this query updates the record when update_time is less than 30 minutes ago, you just need to run script with cron

Comment: I've updated my question with how it looks right now. Still doesn't update. I can't think of anything else..

Comment: forgot mysqli_query... `mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE Price SET price ='.$dollar.',update_time =NOW() WHERE update_time >= (now() - interval 30 minute)");`